# Is there a convenient way to configure EventProcessorClient?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Microsoft provides us nice [Microsoft.Extensions.Azure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/) library which extends IServiceCollection with the set of convenient client configuration methods. For example it allows to configure BlobServiceClient or EventHubConsumerClient with a couple of lines, but I was unable to find a way to configure the [EventProcessorClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient?view=azure-dotnet).

So, the question consists of two parts:

- Is there a way to nicely configure the EventProcessorClient?
- Is it possible to use IAzureClientFactory to create instance of EventProcessorClient by demand?

*Btw, just in case the answer for one or both questions is negative: I'm able to deal with this problem (I just don't want to reinvent the wheel), so exteneded explanation is not required ))*

Comment: I just did a search of the repo you linked to above and could not find any extensions related to `EventProcessorClient`

Comment: [This sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azuremessagingeventhubs-samples/)?

Comment: Yep, @Nkosi, me too, that's the problem ))